# How to pass categorical field to color of marks on 3d scatterplot (three.js & d3.js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, three.js

I want to use a categorical field (Gender) to color the marks on this 3d scatterplot:

https://datavizhokie.github.io/conf-hum-int/

My data format:

**x,y,z,G** 
7,5,8,Male

Originally, the colors were assigned randomly so each node has unique color. However, I updated to use one color, but want to pass the Gender field to color:

```
var pointCount = unfiltered.length;
var pointGeo = new THREE.Geometry();

for (var i = 0; i < pointCount; i ++) {
    var x = xScale(unfiltered[i].x);
    var y = yScale(unfiltered[i].y);
    var z = zScale(unfiltered[i].z);
    pointGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z));
    console.log(pointGeo.vertices);
    pointGeo.vertices[i].angle = Math.atan2(z, x);
    pointGeo.vertices[i].radius = Math.sqrt(x * x + z * z);
    pointGeo.vertices[i].speed = (z / 100) * (x / 100);
    // **** Assign colors to coordinates
    pointGeo.colors.push(new THREE.Color().setRGB(
      //colour.fromarray(G)
      hexToRgb(colour(2)).r / 255, hexToRgb(colour(10)).g / 255, 
      hexToRgb(colour(5)).b / 255
    )); 
}
```

From the three.js documentation, it appears .fromArray may be the way to pass the Gender information, but I've been unsuccessful. This is based on Phil's awesome example:

http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/9852362

Much gratitude to anyone reading this - I'm somewhat new to JS.

Comment: [`.fromArray()`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/fdefb19bdd8dbb7d549fa701b1324bfcd9ff1933/src/math/Color.js#L489) works differently. In the context of how you do the things, it's possible to assign the value of `G` straight to the instance of `THREE.Color()` after pushing it into the array of colours, like: `pointGeo.colors[i].G = unfiltered[i].G;`

Comment: Thanks! Please see my update below.